# Simpledateformat ParseException

Tags: java, android

I need to change the input date format to my desired format.

```
String time = "Fri, 02 Nov 2012 11:58 pm CET";
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm aa z");
Date date = parseFormat.parse(time);
System.out.println("output is " + displayFormat.format(date));
```

it gives me this error

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 02 Nov 2012 11:58 pm CET"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Can anyody help me? Because this code doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't seem throw any error. Did you get one?

Comment: Working fine for me: http://ideone.com/X5q6HH

Comment: Thanks guys, but it still gives me the error, which is up there.

Comment: What is CET ? where to you get this date ?

Comment: @user997777 check my answer it will work

Answer (score 1):

It appears Android's `z` does not accept time zones in the format XXX (such as "CET"). (Pulling from [the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).)

Try this instead:

```
String time = "Fri, 02 Nov 2012 11:58 pm +0100"; // CET = +1hr = +0100
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aa Z"); // Capital Z
Date date = parseFormat.parse(time);

SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
System.out.println("output is " + displayFormat.format(date));
```

> output is 02.11.2012, 22:58

*Note: Also, I think you meant `hh` instead of `HH`, since you have `PM`.*

Result is shown [here](http://ideone.com/sC6tUz). (This uses Java7's `SimpleDateFormat`, but Android should support RFC 822 timezones (`+0100`) as well.)

**NB**: Also, as it appears Android's `z` accepts full names ("Pacific Standard Time" is the example they give), you could simply specify "Centural European Time" instead of "CET".

Comment: Hey, i changed the input string to Sat, 03 Nov 2012 6:29 am but it doesnt work still.

Comment: @user997777 When running the exact code above on an Android project, I encounter no issues. What device are you running this on?

Comment: Java compiler 1.6 and version of api 2.3.5

Comment: Ijust try it on emulator 4.1.2 and it works. I dont understand that

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMMdd");
    System.out.println(date_format.format(cal.getTime()));
```

It will work.. If not print the log cat? What erroe is coming?

Answer (score 0):

First of All I must agree with @Eric answer.

You just need to remove "CET" from your string of date.

Here is sample code. Check it.

```
        String time = "Fri, 02 Nov 2012 11:58 pm CET";
        time = time.replaceAll("CET", "").trim();
        SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm aa");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = parseFormat.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("output is " + displayFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: You probably mean, that im idiot, but it doesnt work. I copy the code, try this string time but still it not works.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt work. I am probably making some mistakes. I try to find them and add the correct code for me.