# How to parse string "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016" to date in android

Tags: java, android, date, android-studio

```
  private void parseDate() {
        String p_localDateTime = "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016";
        SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter,lv_parser;
        String lv_localTimeZone ="";
        lv_localTimeZone="EAT";
        Date lv_localDate = null;

        lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        lv_parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));
        try {
            lv_localDate = lv_parser.parse(p_localDateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("convertLocalTimeToUTC: ");
    }
```

I have tried to parse this date using 3 differnt zone formats 'z','zzz','zzzz' but all throws java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: “Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016” (at offset 20)

Comment: *FYI:* `EAT` is East Africa Time.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, I am able to parse date using above functions using java compilers, but issue is occurring when I try to use same method in android studio. In android its throwing the exception but in java compiler it works fine

Comment: @CoderAndroid Post further info as edits to the Question rather than as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using troublesome old date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

Avoid using `EAT` as a zone. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!). Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). In this particular case, java.time is able to translate that as [`Africa/Nairobi`](http://time.is/Nairobi) zone.

```
String input = "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" ).withLocale ( Locale.US );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

Dump to console. The `toString` method generates a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, extended by appending the name of the zone in brackets. These standard formats are a much better choice for when you need to serialize date-time values to text.

```
System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt );
```

> zdt: 2016-08-08T16:44:19+03:00[Africa/Nairobi]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add the locale:

```
lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Full Example:

```
      String p_localDateTime = "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016";
        SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter,lv_parser;
        String lv_localTimeZone ="";
        lv_localTimeZone="EAT";
        Date lv_localDate = null;

        lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);          //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        lv_parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));
        try {
            lv_localDate = lv_parser.parse(p_localDateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("convertLocalTimeToUTC: ");
```

Comment: Thanks Jens for reply, but Still its throwing same exception after adding Locale.ENGLISH, can you check once if there is anything else i need to do

Comment: @CoderAndroid I have tried it by my own. It works fine

Comment: Can you please  post complete code that you have tried. It will be helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: @CoderAndroid Have added at to my answer. As you can see, i have copied your example and added only the Locale.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am able to parse date using above functions using java compilers, but issue is occurring when I try to use same method in android studio. In android its throwing the exception but in java compiler it works fine

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in below link it appears to be Timezone doesnot accept "ZZZ" format according SimpleDateFormat documentation.
link is:
[Simpledateformat ParseException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206640/simpledateformat-parseexception)

I was able to solve this by mentioning zone as "East Africa Time" instead of "EAT"
and code is:

```
 public void  dateFormatter() {
  String dateString = "Mon Aug 23 8:42:19 East Africa Time 2016";
  String dateFormat= "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat setDateFormatter;
        Date formattedDate = null;
        if(!dateString.isEmpty()) {
            setDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
            try {
                formattedDate = setDateFormatter.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Formatted Date: " + formattedDate);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No error from my side for the code. I change a bit try to output the result and get this

"convertLocalTimeToUTC: Mon Aug 08 21:44:19 SGT 2016"

```
package self.test.out;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class DateParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p_localDateTime = "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016";
        SimpleDateFormat lv_formatter,lv_parser;
        String lv_localTimeZone ="";
        lv_localTimeZone="EAT";
        Date lv_localDate = null;

        lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        //lv_parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        lv_parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(lv_localTimeZone));
        try {
            lv_localDate = lv_parser.parse(p_localDateTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("convertLocalTimeToUTC: "+lv_localDate);
    }
}
```

using Jdk1.6

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am able to parse date using above functions using java compilers, but issue is occurring when I try to use same method in android studio. In android its throwing the exception but in java compiler it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is a utility function that I use in my projects. Just pass the string and the format of the date. In this case the dateformat would be "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy". Hope its helpful.

```
public static Date dateFormatter(String dateString, String dateFormat) {

    SimpleDateFormat setDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date formattedDate = null;
    if (!dateString.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            formattedDate = setDateFormatter.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Parse Exception Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: Can you pl. check once if you can parse the date - "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 EAT 2016". I am getting parse exception in studio, if I user other java compilers it works fine. It will parse  "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 **IST** 2016" but not for  "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 **EAT** 2016".

Comment: try using capital Z once like this "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy" and let me know.

Comment: It is working for the devices below lollipop, but not parsing in devices above lollipop.

Comment: So its now parsing "Mon Aug 08 16:44:19 **EAT** 2016" correctly after using the Z but only on pre lolipop devices is that correct ?

Comment: Even if we use  small 'z' it will parse in pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121597/discussion-between-coder-android-and-gaurav4sarma).